# Mongo-Hadoop streaming

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm new to Mongodb and Hadoop. I'm trying to access mongodb data as input to hadoop mapreduce job. i don't quite know how to specify which collection to use to get data from. this is what i tried:

```
hadoop jar/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar 
-input user/test/input/
-output user/test/output/
-inputformat com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoInputFormat
-outputformat com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoOutputFormat
-io mongodb
-D mongo.input.uri=mongodb://localhost/my_dbs.collectionName 
-D stream.io.identifier.resolver.class=com.mongodb.hadoop.streaming.io.MongoIdentifierResolver 
-mapper /Users/wordcountMapper.py 
-reducer /Users/wordcountReducer.py 
-libjars /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/mongo-hadoop-streaming.jar
```

But i get the following error:

```
ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Unrecognized option: -D
Usage: $HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar [options]
```

and when i tried this, i get another error:

```
 hadoop jar /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar 
-input user/input/ 
-output user/test/output 
-inputformat com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoInputFormat 
-outputformat com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoOutputFormat 
-io mongodb -jobconf mongo.input.uri=mongodb://localhost/my_dbs.collectionName 
-jobconf stream.io.identifier.resolver.class=com.mongodb.hadoop.streaming.io.MongoIdentifierResolver 
-mapper /Users/wordcountMapper.py 
-reducer /Users/wordcountReducer.py 
-libjars /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/mongo-hadoop-streaming.jar

`ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Unrecognized option: -libjars
Usage: $HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar [options]`
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/) link for better idea on how to connect MongoDB to Hadoop.

Edit:

or,

Instead of giving jar with -libjars option, you can directly write it in your driver program as:

```
args.add("-libjars");
args.add("/some/path/to/your/jar");
```

Comment: providing link not a valid answers, check here how to post answers

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer